# How to get the current Zone & Project ID in a GCE startup script?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, metadata, gcloud

TL;DR. I want an instance to describe itself while running a startup script.

---

I'm having a [`startup.sh`](https://github.com/syslogic/insurgency-sandstorm-startup/blob/master/startup.sh) shell script (which I can reference with `--metadata startup-script-url=gs://bucketname/startup.sh`), which depends on a [`steam.exp`](https://github.com/syslogic/insurgency-sandstorm-startup/blob/master/steam.exp) expect script. Therefore I'd like to know the name of the bucket, which was used; eg. from meta-data `startup-script-url`. It is being assumed that both files reside in the same bucket, but only one of them can be referenced.

I'm trying to get the meta-data `startup-script-url` and then extract the bucket name in shell script (to be added into `startup.sh`, in order to fetch the `gs://bucketname/steam.exp` before running it).

What I have tried so far:

```
gcloud compute instances describe $HOSTNAME \
  --zone=europe-west3-c \
  --project=some-project \
  --flatten="metadata[startup-script-url]"
```

But this is not portable, as it would need to be the current project ID and current zone.

How to obtain these values in a startup script? I haven't tried `printenv` yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can get the `project` alike this:

```
PROJECT_ID=`gcloud config get-value project`
```

And then obtain the `zone` with:

```
gcloud compute instances list \
  --project=$PROJECT_ID \
  --filter=name:$HOSTNAME \
  --format="table[csv,no-heading](zone)"
```

This requires permission `gcloud.compute.instances.list`, which role `roles/compute.viewer` has.

Meanwhile I've also found Google Cloud 
[Game Servers](https://cloud.google.com/game-servers) (beta).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the VM metadata with curl:

```
STARTUP_SCRIPT_URL=`curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/my-startup-script-url" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
```

You can also get other values from the metadata server, like GCP Project ID and the VM's zone. Curl seems to be faster than gcloud:

```
GCP_PROJECT_ID=`curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`

GCP_ZONE=$(basename `curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`)

GCP_REGION="${GCP_ZONE::-2}"
```

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values

Comment: Sorry, but why would I want to use cURL? This only adds lots of complexity with zero advance. And it also may work in Linux.

Comment: One benefit would be much faster execution than the python gcloud cli